# Why React-Create-App fails to read ReactRouter data type?

Tags: reactjs, compilation, create-react-app, react-router-v4

I try currently to build a React-Create-App. It's a package available on github - latest commit  8 days ago.

My compiler fails to translate my ReactRouters code.

Here my App.js code, first edit:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <Router>
           <div className="App">
              <Route path='/' render={
                  ()=> {
                    return (<h1> Welcome Home </h1> ) ;

                  }

              }/>
           </div>
     </Router>
    );
  }
} 


export default App;
```

The error log is the following :

> Failed to compile.
>
> Error in ./src/App.js Module not found: 'react-router-dom' in
> [current folder]

> @ ./src/App.js 16:22-49

But when I eject my ReactCreateApp I effectively see a react-router-dom in package JSON:

- `{ "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2" }`

How do I fix this?

Comment: You're defining `Router` in your code. However, when you import react-router-dom, Router is no where to be found. To fix the issue, you can set `BrowserRouter` as an alias to `Router`. For example, `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';`

Comment: thank for your comment Curious13, I have edit my code but still, the same answer

Comment: you shouldn't need to eject afaik, react-router-dom should have been in your package.json all along. If it wasn't, then install it with npm install --save react-router-dom.

Comment: Wow, just reinstall react-router-dom work. Seems some bugg on Create-React-App installation. As I have seen it was present on my ejected package json, I have don t think to try this ° desparate ° trick, but yes that was this ! thank Nikrb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this in a codesandbox and it works fine. Have a look here. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/7o3qjyy6

Try an npm install?

> > EDIT

I created an app this time without codesandbox.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app/
```

Added the line in package.json as create-react-app itself says for adding a router like this here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-router

```
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
```

Did an

`npm i`

and it worked.

Comment: effectively as I just said to nikrb I have don t try an install because I have seen the react-router-dom on package JSON when ejected, but that was the solution, thank you all for your useful propositions. So, seems the lesson is to check the installation despite the presence in package json

Comment: Hey @j-doe, I re-ran the steps and created the my-app again and then did a ``` npm run eject ```, it didn't contain react-router-dom for me.  

`
cat package.json  | grep react

"babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.1",
"eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
"react": "^16.3.2",
"react-dev-utils": "^5.0.1",
"react-dom": "^16.3.2",
"^react-native$": "react-native-web"
"react-app"
"extends": "react-app"
`

Comment: OKAY thank for your feedback dixitk, hmm... In my package it appears, but I fail now to launch the ejected version of ReactCreateApp. So seems there is a step in my coding I have miss. I let my post for information purposes, in case other people have difficulties on this point. Second lesson is to redo all the steps to ensure there is no missing path.